# Pythonanywhere How to Choose Different Install Directory

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

Getting following when installing modules.  Get like message trying to install other modules.

Help greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-p

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --pre
the distutils default setting) was:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need t
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have admini
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different install
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH enviro
variable.

Comment: You just need to run your installation app (pip or easyinstall) with `sudo`

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to install a module in that directory, the error is saying that you'll need root permissions to do so. If you were working on a PC where you have root permission, you could do

```
sudo pip install module
```

For PythonAnywhere, you can use the [user install](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#user-installs) feature

```
pip install module --user
```

to avoid permission conflicts.

Alternatively, install [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and use that to make environments. `pip install` can be used without `sudo` or `--user` in that case.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- the `--user` flag or a virtualenv is the way to go on PythonAnywhere, we don't support `sudo` (yet)

Comment: Thank you, @GilesThomas, updated the answer to clarify your point.

Answer (score 0):

To install it in your user `site-packages` directory, use `--user`. To install it somewhere else, use `-t`, for example: `pip3 install module -t ~/path/to/directory`